# Problem when importing slick into my sbt project

Tags: scala, sbt, slick

I can't import Slick into my .sbt project. Any other dependencies work as expected but this one refuses to cooperate. I don't really see where the problem is (I'm a Scala newbie)

Logs from Intelij

```
Error while importing sbt project:

List([info] Loading global plugins from myFolder\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[info] Loading project definition from myFolder\IdeaProjects\myproject\project
[info] Loading settings for project myproject from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to myproject (in build file:/myFolder/IdeaProjects/myproject/)
[info] sbt server started at local:sbt-server-8a59bd6991d33f8fc379
sbt:myproject>
[info] Defining Global / sbtStructureOptions, Global / sbtStructureOutputFile and 1 others.
[info] The new values will be used by cleanKeepGlobs
[info]  Run `last` for details.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to myproject (in build file:/myFolder/IdeaProjects/myproject/)
[info] Applying State transformations org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks from myFolder/.IdeaIC2019.2/config/plugins/Scala/repo/org.jetbrains/sbt-structure-extractor/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2018.2.1+4-88400d3f/jars/sbt-structure-extractor.jar
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to myproject (in build file:/myFolder/IdeaProjects/myproject/)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last update' for the full output
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last ssExtractDependencies' for the full output
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.slick:slick_2.13:3.2.1
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: myFolder\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.slick\slick_2.13\3.2.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/slick/slick_2.13/3.2.1/slick_2.13-3.2.1.pom
[error] (ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.slick:slick_2.13:3.2.1
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: myFolder\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.slick\slick_2.13\3.2.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/slick/slick_2.13/3.2.1/slick_2.13-3.2.1.pom
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 2019-10-25 13:04:21
[info] shutting down sbt server)
```

build.sbt

```
name := "myproject"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.1",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.7.26",
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Scala 2.13 you need Slick 3.3.2

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/slick/slick_2.13/

If you use Slick 3.2.1 you need Scala 2.12

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/slick/slick_2.12/